# Flask-SQLalchemy second layer query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to obtain the information contained in "DATA" with the following tables:

```
class Table_1(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table_2.id'))
    table_4_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table_4.id'))


class Table_2(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_3_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table_3.id'))
    NAME = db.Column(db.String(60))
    table_1 = db.relationship('Table_1', backref='table_1_table_2', lazy=True)

class Table_3(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    DATA = db.Column(db.String(60))
    table_2 = db.relationship('Table_2', backref='table_2_table_3', lazy=True)
```

I can get the value of of NAME with 
`Table_1.query.join(Table_2).add_columns(Table_2.NAME).all()`. How can i `add_column(Table_3.Data)`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no relationship between Table_1 and Table_3. Only through Table_2 (Table_2 has table_3_id). Any thoughts?

Comment: `...join(Table_2).join(Table_3)...`

Comment: What is the diference between `join(Table_2,Table_3)` and `join(Table_2).join(Table_3)`?

Comment: Or, lets say we have another table (`Table_4`) which has a relationship with `Table_3` (just like `Table_2` has). How should i call the `join` statements to retrieve the data related to `Table_2` and not the one related to `Table_4`?

Comment: To the first, there should be no difference, I think. Consult the [`Query.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) docs. I think it allows multiple target entities in the same vein as it does multiple relationship "on clause" arguments. The latter comment is a bit complicated as a sentence without concrete models.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question to show the answers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to Ilja Everilä for his guidance! The answer is to join consecutively th Tables i need. So, in this case: `Table_1.query.join(Table_2).join(Table_3).add_column(Table_3.DATA).all()` does the trick.

Now, if i add another table like this one:

```
 class Table_4(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     table_3_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table_3.id'))
     SOMETHING = db.Column(db.String(60))
     table_1 = db.relationship('Table_1', backref='table_1_table_2', lazy=True)
```

Things get complicated. But as Ilja Everilä stated, we can use onclause to point the query in the right direction:

`Table_1.query.join(Table_2, Table_1.table_2_id = Table_2.id).join(Table_4,Table_1.table_4_id =Table_4.id).join(Table_3).add_columns(Table_2.NAME,Table_3.DATA,Table_4.SOMETHING).all()`